# Change cursor when div scrolls up or down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, cursor

I have a div that implements Scriptperlative's CursorDivScroll script. How can I implement two customized cursors in the div that is using the script; one that shows when scrolling down and one that shows when scrolling up? Here is the javascript and HTML that I have thus far. The javascript is just the CursorDivScroll script.

```
 <script type='text/javascript' >
     $(document).ready(function() {
 CursorDivScroll( 'repertoirescroll', 40, 40 ).noHorizontal();
     });
 </script> 


 #repertoirescroll {
 cursor: url(../images/arrow.png), auto;
 position:relative;

 }
```

Thanks for any help in advance. I think I need to implement an if statement that says if mousemove = mousedown use this cursor else if mousemove = up use this cursor...? Not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Checking if the scrollTop is decreasing or increasing should tell you if it's scrolling up or down, and then just set the cursor based on that when scrolling, and use a timeout to reset the cursor when scrolling stops :

```
var top=0, timer;

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop(),
        cursor = scrollTop > top ? 'pointer' : 'wait';
    $('body').css('cursor', cursor);
    top = scrollTop;
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        $('body').css('cursor', 'default');
    }, 500);
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JjjtN/)

Comment: I am trying to implement this-- not sure which variables I need to change here to use the div #repertoirescroll that I have and the up pointing cursor I have (shown in the above css). Can you expand on this a little for me? I appreciate it!

Comment: The plugin seems very outdated, but it does change the scrollTop, so the code above will work fine. All you have to do is change `window` with whatever element you're trying to scroll, like `#repertoirescroll`, and it should work, see this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JjjtN/1/) for an example. In the script above `pointer`, `wait` and `default` are the cursors I used, just change that with whatever floats your boat, like `url(someimage.png)` or whatever.

Comment: I see that what you have done works, but is this the correct way to write mine?         $('body').css('cursor', 'url(images/arrow.png)');

Comment: Yes, I believe so? Just passing the `url(image)` as a string to `css()` should work!

Comment: hmmm...it's not working for me for some reason. Have you tried using an image?

Comment: Yes, and it should be working, however it does'nt seem to work in jsFiddle, but it does in [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/uvikiw/1/edit) ?

Comment: hmmm...it actually isn't working there either- the cursor does not appear to be showing any image other than the default cursor and the pointer-- still cannot get this to work with an actual image